# Find nullspace of this matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

The question I have is this:

1) Find a basis for the solution space of the homogeneous linear system.

$$x - y + 2z = 0 \\
2x + y = 0 \\
x − 4y + 6z = 0$$

So I convert to a matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 & 2 \\ 2 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & -4 & 6 \end{bmatrix}$$
$$ -> \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 & 2 \\ 0 & 3 & -4 \\ 0 & -3 & 4 \end{bmatrix}$$

$$ -> \begin{bmatrix} 1 & -1 & 2 \\ 0 & 3 & -4 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

So is this right?

Let $z = t, y = \frac{4}{3}t, x = -2t + \frac{4}{3}t$

so:

$$ -> \begin{bmatrix} x & y & z \end{bmatrix}$$
$$ -> \begin{bmatrix} \frac{-2}{3}t & \frac{4}{3}t & t \end{bmatrix}$$
$$ -> t * \begin{bmatrix} \frac{-2}{3} & \frac{4}{3} & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

So the basis is:

$$ -> \begin{bmatrix} \frac{-2}{3} & \frac{4}{3} & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

Is this right?

More generally, the reason we do it this way is because we're trying to solve for x in the equation $Ax = 0$ so we have to reduce A, setup a system of equations that result when you multiply A by X, setup any free variables, extract the coefficients and that's the basis of the nullspace (the set of all solutions to Ax = 0). Does that sound right?

Answer (score 4):

Yes,
It looks perfectly fine. Since $\operatorname{rank}(A) = 2$, ($A$ is the matrix form of your equation) it means that the dimension of the null space is equal to one (a line in $\mathbb{R}^3$). The basis is just a vector, that is usually normalized with a norm of $1$.

If you check your solution it works well.

Hope that helps.

Romain

Comment: How do you know the rank is 2?

Comment: After doing some elementary row operations on the matrix $A$ you have $2$ linearly independent rows, therefore, $\operatorname{rank}(A)=2$.

Comment: How do you know that they are linearly independent so quickly?

Comment: If you look at the two vectors ($v_1=[1 ,-1 ,2]$ and $v_2=[0, 3, -4]$) the only way to get a null vector with a weighted sum i.e. $a_1  v_1 + a_2 v_2 = [0, 0, 0]$ is to have $a_1$ equal to zero for the $x$ entry. Then, $a_2=0$ follows for the other two entries.

Comment: Can you rephrase this? $a_1$ and $a_2$ are constants here right? What do you mean other two entries?

Comment: Yes exactly, $a_1$ and $a_2$ are constants, by definition if there exists a pair of constants ( $a_1$, $a_2$) $\neq$ $(0, 0)$ such that $a_1  v_1 + a_2 v_2 = [0, 0, 0]$, then $a_1$ and $a_2$ are **linearly** dependent. In, your case you need $a_1 = 0$ for the entry $x$ and $a_2 = 0$ for the entries $y$ and $z$. Hope it is clearer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like the right method to get the rational basis for the null space. Quick check also shows that 
$$
\left[
    \begin{matrix}
    1 & -1 & 2 \\
    2 & 1 & 0 \\
    1 & -4 & 6 \\
    \end{matrix}
\right]
\left[
    \begin{matrix}
    -2/3  \\
    4/3  \\
    1  \\
    \end{matrix}
\right] =
\left[
    \begin{matrix}
    0  \\
    0  \\
    0  \\
    \end{matrix}
\right]
$$